# How to create a branch from a prior revision without affecting the latest revision using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: windows, svn, branch, tortoisesvn

I have Tortoise SVN, but never created a branch to work on to make some changes to a prior revision only. I think I was doing it correctly, but it did not work as expected. I have some screens I was prompted with and questions related to them.

My goal is to having both working copies on my PC, and be able to switch between them as needed. Here's the steps I performed:

1. From the repo browser, I found the revision I want, and right click.
2. Click the radio button Specific revision, and I enter revision 249.
3. Click on ellipsis next to the "To Path" (brings up new dialog with a URL that populates with existing Trunk.
4. I change the URL to a new path where I want the revision to work on.
5. I clicked on the black box adjacent to Revision (a select revision dialog appears).
6. I change from HEAD to Revision and enter 249 (again), then clicked OK to close the Select Revision box. It then created the new branch on the repository.

Here's what happened:
After I created the branch with the new URL, I was prompted to checkout the new branch. Unfortunately, it wrote over my WC Trunk of the latest version. I am not sure why it did not prompt me for the local WC folder name?

Fortunately, I had a backup of the latest WC on my PC, and was able to rename the revision to Trunk Version 62.5 and then renamed my copy of the latest revision to Trunk.

Now I am afraid how to commit changes I made on the Trunk Version 62.5 or on the Trunk of latest version. I am fearful it will overwrite the latest version on the repository. I am not sure what I did wrong.

[image: Dialog boxes that are presented as I try to make a branch]

Comment: What do you see in the repo browser for  the top folder? You should see your new branch there, as well as an untouched trunk. Does your repo follow the `/tags`, `/branches` and `/trunk` convention?

Comment: The repo browser shows as: 
 "http://myproject.com/VS1Y/branches/version_61.5"

Answer (score 0):

First four steps of the procedure look good, but the rest is unclear. I would recommend that you read the following pages:

- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Branching / Tagging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-branch-1),
- [SVNBook | Using Branches](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/).

You need to create a branch first (and I assume that you did this). Next, you need to checkout a new working copy of this branch. You can switch your existing working copy to the branch, but you've mentioned that you want to have two independent working copies: one of your branch and of the trunk. That's why I say that you need to check out a new working copy.

Note that revision history in Subversion is ummutable — changes committed into a repository remain there forever. So your commits cannot actually delete anything in the repository and cannot permanently rewrite any data. You can recover if you make any mistake.

Comment: I think I made the mistake by not creating a branch in my WC first and then checkout the branch in the repository to the new branch folder. I assumed (incorrectly), that the branch would be created from the original trunk in my Trunk's WC when I did the checkout to it.